# how to keep cache on other server

Tags: .net

My web server and database server, they consume their memory to their fullest.

so I have decided to use the cache to improve performance. there are many techniques available in asp.net and SQL server to keep cache objects

on the same server, but I want to keep it on other servers ( that is the third server).

I can use web farms for the purpose but I do not want to use it. so except web farms, is there any other way exists where I can keep the cache on the third server?
note: I do not want to use remoting also.

yours sincerely

Comment: You can use redis server. For detail refer this : https://redis.io/documentation and https://www.tutorialspoint.com/redis/

Comment: we are not using core also. is redis available from webform also?

Comment: Additional network roundtrips seems like one of the last things you should be introducing if you're wanting to improve performance.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever I would say it depends :) One roundtrip can be hundreds times less than making a call. For example, if you get data from your database and from external services, aggregate and process it, make calculations. I agree that you need to be careful to not bring regression here.

Comment: @user3129097 Redis can be used in web form also?